# Timestamp Difference and get hours, minutes, and seconds alone

Tags: mysql, time, diff

So i have 2 tables in each row, i used this to get the avg time in minutes.

```
SELECT Sec_to_time (Avg (Timestampdiff (second, `survival`, `lastupdate`)))
FROM   main
```

But i want to get the hours, minutes, and seconds alone so i can echo them in php.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the MySQL [HOUR(), MINUTE() and SECOND()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html) functions to break the time returned from SEC_TO_TIME into its components.

To avoid having to repeat yourself, you can wrap the calculation:

```
SELECT HOUR(x.timeDiff), MINUTE(x.timeDiff), SECOND(x.timeDiff) 
FROM 
  (
    SELECT Sec_to_time(Avg (Timestampdiff (second, `survival`, `lastupdate`))) as timeDiff
    FROM main
  ) AS x
```

[SqlFiddle Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/1448)

Comment: Thank you, that works perfectly. But how would i echo out each hour, minute, and second?

Answer (score 0):

There are hour(), minute() and second() functions in MySql.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
select concat(HOUR(Sec_to_time(Avg (Timestampdiff (second, login_datetime, logout_datetime)))),
  'hr ',
  MINUTE(Sec_to_time(Avg (Timestampdiff (second, login_datetime, logout_datetime)))),
  'min ',
  SECOND(Sec_to_time(Avg (Timestampdiff (second, login_datetime, logout_datetime)))), 
  'sec ') 
as his_time from table_name;
```